# Swichcase not working in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am stuck in swich case. Please check code below

```
Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ pos",""+posSel_lay);
String ff=Integer.toString(posSel_lay);
//var ffs=Integer.toString(posSel_lay);
Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ pos",""+ff);
if(ff.equals("0")){
    Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Lagan","");
}else if(ff.equals("1")){
    Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@MBBS","");
}else if(ff.equals("2")){
    Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@JODHA","");
}else if(ff.equals("3")){
    Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ZINDAGI","");
}
```

I got log only this line
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ pos  2
& its not going in swich case why i dont know, can you help me please?

Comment: I don't see a `switch` statement. You have an `if...else if` chain. Only one branch is going to execute. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I forget to put switch case. I used both if else & also switch case. In both its not going in condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I get this posSel_lay from bundle which is passed by other activity.Previously i written switch code in on button click so now i changed flow,
When i am getting value of posSel_lay from bundle that time only i written code of switch 
& there i am making some boolean values true or false which is declared locally. And when user 
clicks on button that time i used boolean variables for checking. Then its done.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are good.

but you should at least put any message into message param of Log. otherwise you will not able to see this in logs

```
Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ZINDAGI","some message.");
```

Answer (score 0):

By default a switch case works WITH integers, why don't you try something like the following:

```
Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ pos",""+posSel_lay);

switch (posSel_lay){
    case 0:
        Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Lagan","");
        break;
    case 1:
        Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@MBBS","");
        break;
    case 2:
        Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@JODHA","");
        break;
    case 3:
        Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ZINDAGI","");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Now instead of converting to a string, and using an if-else chain, you use a select statement, which IMO is much cleaner.

Comment: Hi Jack, tried this method with int value but its not going in swich case dude whats the problem.

Comment: I don't know, have you debugged to see what the value of posSel_lay is?

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ pos", "" + posSel_lay );

switch( posSel_lay ) {
  case 0:
    Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Lagan","");
    break;
  case 1:
    Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@MBBS","");
    break;
  case 2:
    Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@JODHA","");
    break;
  case 3:
    Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ZINDAGI","");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand your question , but here is **SwitchCase**

```
switch(posSel_lay){

  case 0: 
       Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Lagan","");
       break;

  case 1: 
       Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@MBBS","");
       break;

  case 2: 
       Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@JODHA","");
       break;

   case 3: 
       Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ZINDAGI","");
       break;
  }
```

Comment: ya but in log i getting what is value of posSel_lay but switch is not working that means its not going to check any condition.